# How to adjust Large Table in two column paper?

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column

Can anyone help me to adjust following table in two column paper (As did in the picture). I read several solutions here but can't fix this issue. Table should be in top of the two column text and should expand over the two columns. Will be really thankful.

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Ttile}
\label{tab:Comparison}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Reference and \\ Publication Year\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{Study Focus} &
  \textbf{Results and Outcomes} &
  \textbf{Artifacts of Investigation} &
  \textbf{Method of Investigation} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Manual\\ Efforts\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Tool \\ Support\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Repository and Architectural Mining}} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}1{]}\\    \\ 2018\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}2{]}\\    \\ 2017\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}3{]}\\    \\ 2018\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}12{]}\\    \\ 2020\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Tools for Static and Dynamic Analysis}} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}5{]}\\    \\ 2020\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}6{]}\\    \\ 2020\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}9{]}\\    \\ 2020\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}14{]}\\    \\ 2020\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Practitioner-based Surveys}} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}4{]}\\    \\ 2019\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✕ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}7{]}\\    \\ 2018\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✔ \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{[}13{]}\\    \\ 2018\end{tabular} &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
Proposed study &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  Detecting   bad smell in MSA code &
  ✔ &
  ✕ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you try using the  `table*` environment?

Comment: Depending on the margin size, font size and actual contents of your table, you might also have to adjust the column widths as the table most likely is still too wide for the available space.

Comment: off-topic, but consider also use the `booktabs` package.